# How to change mapping parameters on front end input?

Tags: angular

I am currently trying to build an angular app that is able to accept a .csv file with any number of columns and any column name and manipulate this .csv to reflect a template of 3 columns with specific column names to be uploaded to the back end.

For example:

`date | location | customer | order_value | order_id`

or

`Date | loc      | cust     | ord_v       | id       | other..value..fields |....`

and change these to a standard

`| customer | order_value | order_id |`

for back end computation.

My current approach is to preview the inputted .csv and prompt the user to input the matching fields. For example:

`customer: cust
order_value: ord_v
order_id : id`

And use these inputs to map to a standard JSON file after using Papaparse.

Assume this.data is a JSON file with headers mapped to the input .csv

```js
mapped_data = this.data.map( u => ({ customer : u.input_cust, order_value : u.input_order_v, order_id : input_id})
```

This is not working due to the "input" variables being strings and they need to be properties of the "u" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data["property"]` operator is the equivalent to the `data.property` operator. This can be done in a map() as seen below to handle multiple variables at once based off of a preset variable (in my instance an input variable from the front end). Below is an example;

```
mapped_data = this.data.map( u => ({ customer : u[input_cust], order_value : u[input_order_v], order_id : u[input_id]})
```